# WiX Bootstrapper with custom WPF UI, canceling a single package from a bundle

Tags: c#, wpf, wix, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I have a wix bootstrapper project with multiple packages setup through bootstrapper bundle, and I'm having hard time to cancel a single package from the bundle. I use a custom WPF UI for my installer, and my goal is to do this job from *my* installer where I implement all bootstrapper events.

Setting up the `e.Result = Result.Cancel` in any event (e.g. in events like `ExecuteProgress`, `ExecutePackageBegin`, `ExecutePackageComplete`, `DetectPackageBegin` or `DetectPackageComplete`) doesn't do any good.

While `e.Result = Result.Cancel` assignment in `ExecuteProgress` event cancels/rolls back the whole installation, this same setup does in fact cancel/rollback the whole installation in the package level events too (e.g. in events like: `ExecutePackageBegin`, `ExecutePackageComplete`, `DetectPackageBegin` or `DetectPackageComplete`).

Is there any solution for this?

Again, my goal is to cancel a single (or few) packages arbitrarily, ignoring any rules setup in the bundle, using bootstrapper events in custom UI.

(I'm using Wix 3.14 and Visual Studio 2019 with Wix extension)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The bundle is designed to support rollback so that if anything goes wrong during execution, the machine is put back to the previous state as if nothing happened. The bundle is supposed to be a collection of packages that need to be installed and uninstalled together. What the BootstrapperApplication is supposed to do is determine which packages it wants installed during Plan, and only request the packages that it wants installed (`OnPlanPackageBegin`). It can't change the plan during Apply.

Comment: Understood, thanks for the answer. So, how to change the plan on runtime,  on the fly? As I can see from the wix bundle schema, a single bundle is associated with a single custom UI with a single chain, and multiple packages. The only way to change the plan is to associate some variable to a package `DetectCondition` property. Now the solution moves to another "space;" is there a way to set a wix variable from a custom installer (wpf custom ui project).

Comment: StackOverflow is not a good place for these kinds of questions. You might want to try the [wix-users mailing list](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/mailinglist/) or [GitHub discussions](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/discussions?discussions_q=category%3AQuestions).